# Django querying foreign key from backward

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to query from backward: at fist see my models:

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('blog.Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
```

I have many category and many post, one category name is `tech` I am trying to get all the post those are in `tech` category.

I  tried like this. `Category.objects.filter(contain__exact='tech')` but it is not work anymore.

Can anyone help me to figure get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Best way to get all the post in tech category using foreign key.**

```
tech_blogs = Blog.objects.filter(category__name__icontains='tech')
```

and also change

```
category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```